# Qt: How to manage QObject classes across dll and executable?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, qobject

I have a Qt+cmake project in Win10.
The project structure is

- Main

  - MainWindow
- DLL1

  - Class1
- DLL2

  - Class2

Class1 and Class2 are both child classes of QObject. MainWindow, as an executable, includes both Class1 and Class2. Class2 includes Class1. However, the compiler alerts:

```
mocs_compilation.cpp.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const Class1::staticMetaObject" ...
Class2.cpp.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const Class1::staticMetaObject" ...
```

I have done:

1. Define Macro for exporting class from dll.

```
#if defined(DLL_DECL)
#define DLL_DECL_SPEC Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
# define DLL_DECL_SPEC Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

2. Class1 is defined in such a way.

```
class DLL_DECL_SPEC Class1: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
}
```

3. Class1 can be successfully instantiated in MainWindow.
4. When Class2 includes Class1, the compilation always failed with the above errors.

I have tried:

1. The other non-QObject classes can be successfully instantiated in both MainWindow and Class2.
2. I have checked the target_link_libraries. Main links DLL1 and DLL2. DLL2 links DLL1.
3. I tried declaring Class1 by only its name in header of Class2 and `#include "Class1.h"` in cpp of Class2. The error still remains...

Do you have any idea about these errors? In Qt, is one QObject class only allowed to be used once? Is there any way to work around?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I do nothing special (over the normal exporting of symbols in a dll) to make this work. And yes I am using Qt + CMake + dlls + Visual Studio,

Comment: You have to have **separate *DLL\_DECL\_SPEC* for each *.dll*** (each only defined in its own *.dll*), so you'd need to `#if defined(DLL_DECL1) #define DLL_DECL_SPEC1 ...`, and `#if defined(DLL_DECL2) #define DLL_DECL_SPEC2 ...`. *P.S.*: this is not *Qt* related. :)

Comment: Thank you CristiFati! Exactly like what you said. I renamed the macro and it is solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

As CristiFati mentioned, I create one ModuleXX.h for each dynamic library.

```
#if defined(DLL_DECLXX)
#define DLLXX_DECL_SPEC Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
# define DLLXX_DECL_SPEC Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

In CMakeLists.txt, I rename the definitions as `add_definitions(-DDLL_DECLXX)`. Now the include problem has been solved.

Comment: That silences the linker but doesn't solve your real issue. See [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries).

Comment: @IInspectable: Why do you think the real issue is still unresolved? This was a classic `__declspec(dllexport)`, `__declspec(dllimport)` mismatch example. The *.dll* boundary cross + static *UCRT*s is another generic problem, but I didn't see the latter mentioned in the question.

Comment: @cri You don't see the latter issue mentioned because it is the one that's so difficult to debug and attribute to any root cause that most will just move on and subscribe it to the OS being funky.

Comment: True, it's *Undefined Behavior*, but in the *IDE*, */MD(d)* is selected by default (I suppose it's same on command line, but I'm not on *Win* right now to confirm / infirm). So unless one doesn't explicitly change that, won't run into the issue. I assumed *OP* would mention this fact if they did it, (that's why I said I didn't see it in the question).

Comment: @cri The `/MD[d]` command line option is not sufficient to prevent the potential issues.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you for the kind remind. I will keep the CRT issue in mind. Maybe it would be a better strategy to avoid unnecessary calling across DLLs.